# MySQL/PHP/Wordpress - php result object contains members with function names - how to dereference?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

in a normal SQL table i have a date field called date1. I have a query that asks for the date1 field and for the monthname and weekday of that field and outputs the raw data on a web page...

```
$result = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT date1, MONTHNAME(date1), WEEKDAY(date1) FROM my_table");
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result);
echo "</pre>";
```

with the following result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
        [date1] => 2013-08-26
        [MONTHNAME(date1)] => August
        [WEEKDAY(date1)] => 0
    )
)
```

But how do I get about dereferencing the monthname (or weekday) part of the result?

```
foreach($result as $i => $entry) {
    $date = $entry->date1;           // works as expected
    $m = $entry->MONTHNAME(date1);   // does not work - also as expected...
}
```

The result is a `Fatal error: Call to undefined method stdClass::MONTHNAME()`.

I could use the wordpress option to obtain the query result as an array of arrays (and keep track of what index would correspond what part of the result) but is there any way to quote the variable name that happens to have the form of a method call and make it behave as an ordinary object variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT date1, MONTHNAME(date1) AS `month`, WEEKDAY(date1) AS `week` FROM my_table
```

now you can use `$entry->month` and `$entry->week`